# Use Basecamp (BCX) API with Yeoman

Tags: api, yeoman, basecamp, yeoman-generator

I want to write a [Yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/generators.html) to setup new projects. During this process, I want it to create a new project in Basecamp. Is it possible to hit the [BCX API](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api) — or any API for that matter — with Yeoman? And how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found this out by myself and it really isn’t that difficult. I just used the [**request** node module](https://npmjs.org/package/request) to do this.

For the BCX API and my project in particular I did it this way (inside a Yeoman Generator):

```
var r = request.defaults({
  'auth': {
    'user': 'USERNAME',
    'pass': 'PASSWORD',
    'sendImmediately': true
  },
  'header': {
    'User-Agent': 'PROJECT NAME (EMAIL_ADDRESS)'
  }
});

r.post({
  'url': 'https://basecamp.com/ACCOUNT_ID/api/v1/projects.json',
  'json': true,
  'body': {
    'name': 'foobar'
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  // Callback Stuff
});
```

I hope this helps anyone.